# Программно достучаться до строковых ресурсов чужого приложения

Tags: swift, xcode

Есть следующая проблема: часто сталкиваюсь с приложениями, в которых вообще не предусмотрен приемлемый язык. Т.е. приложение написано только для аборигенов и экспаты не имеют возможности выбрать другой язык, например, английский, как наиболее распространенный. Пробовал искать в Google на эту тему, но не нашел ничего, что могло бы подтолкнуть куда копать. Насколько реально программно достучаться до строковых ресурсов чужого приложения с целью сделать соответствующий перевод?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если совсем просто, то хотелось бы написать приложение, которое могло бы переводить все строки чужого приложения на конкретный язык. Возможно, выдать поверх свой экран с текстом перевода по нажатию, например, какой либо кнопки.

Comment: Как вариант, сделать снимок экрана и вызвать некий API для перевода. Насколько это реально?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, вы не можете читать ресурсы другого приложения. Но вы можете создать свое приложение, в которое будете загружать сделанные снимки экрана, распознавать текст и переводить его.

Comment: Подсознательно я это я понимал (это Apple), потому и высказал такую идею. Вопрос как делать распознавание и перевод текста? Google API или есть встроенные средства? В IOS 16 есть "живой текст". Можно ли как-то это прикрутить через Swift?

Comment: В Swift есть фреймворки для распознавания, см. тот же Vision. Для перевода - любой подходящий API Google, Microsoft и т.д.

Comment: Да,  нашел. Спасибо, буду копать.